# C++: How to avoid redefinition of structs and classes without modifying the header file

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am writing two classes: a Tree class (Tree) and a binary search tree (BST) that inherits from the Tree class. However, when I compile my code, I get a plethora of errors, stating that I redefined the struct TreeNode, the tree class (Tree) binary search tree (BST) class. The autograder system **does not allow me to modify the header file (datastructure.hpp) in any way, shape, or form**, so using include guards on the header file is not a viable solution. Is there any other way to avoid redefinition errors without using include guards?

```
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/tree.cpp:2,
                 from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:3:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:9:16: error: redefinition of ‘struct TreeNode’
    9 | typedef struct TreeNode {
      |                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:2:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:9:16: note: previous definition of ‘struct TreeNode’
    9 | typedef struct TreeNode {
      |                ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/tree.cpp:2,
                 from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:3:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:15:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef int TreeNode’
   15 | } TreeNode;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:2:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:15:3: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct TreeNode TreeNode’
   15 | } TreeNode;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/tree.cpp:2,
                 from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:3:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:17:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Tree’
   17 | class Tree {
      |       ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:2:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:17:7: note: previous definition of ‘class Tree’
   17 | class Tree {
      |       ^~~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/tree.cpp:2,
                 from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/bst.cpp:3:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/AlgorithmicTraining/src/datastructure.hpp:26:7: error: redefinition of ‘class BST’
   26 | class BST: public Tree {
      |       ^~~
In file included from /home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/ECS36C Homework 3/src/bst.cpp:2:
/home/ubuntu/eclipse-workspace/ECS36C Homework 3/src/datastructure.hpp:26:7: note: previous definition of ‘class BST’
   26 | class BST: public Tree {
      |       ^~~
```

This seems strange, considering that I have not redefined any of the class constructors or used any constructors that are non-existent in the class header file (`datastructure.hpp`) file:

Below is my code (`datastructure.hpp`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct TreeNode { 
   int key;
   int val;
   bool flag;
   int num_children;
   TreeNode **children;
} TreeNode; 

class Tree {
    protected:
        TreeNode* root;
        int max_width;
    public:
        Tree(int width);
        static void solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path);
};

class BST: public Tree {
    protected:
        int max_width = 2;
        
    public:
        BST();
        static void solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path);
};
```

Below is my code for the `Tree` class (`tree.cpp`):

```
#include "datastructure.hpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <queue> 

using namespace std;

// Constructor
Tree::Tree(int width) {
    max_width = width;
}

void Tree::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path)
{
}
```

Below is my code for the `BST` class (`bst.cpp`):

```
#include "datastructure.hpp"
#include "tree.cpp"

#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

BST::BST() : Tree(2) {
}

void BST::solution(const char *input_path, const char *output_path)
{
}
```

Comment: Do not #include .cpp files, that's the solution.

Comment: Which book or tutorial do you follow? Does it tell you to use `typedef` for classes? A class (and `struct`) name *is* a type-name already, you don't need `typedef`. E.g. `class TreeNode { ... };` is enough to define the "type" `TreeNode`.

Comment: Whichever online course, or textbook, or C++ instructor, directed you to put `using namespace std;` into a header file and then prevented you from fixing this egregious error and improper C++ usage: it is urgently important for you to ***immediately*** get rid of this online course, textbook, or C++ instructor right away. You are not being taught proper C++, and are just setting yourself up for a world of hurt, later down the road. Although there is a simple workaround for the issue you asked about, it is more important for you to fix the more fundamental problem here.

Comment: why without modifiying the header? Your headers should have include guards (and you sould not include source files)

Comment: is datastructure.hpp unmodifieable file missing the header guard?

Comment: Remove the `#include tree.cpp` from bst.cpp.     That (at least partially) addresses the specific problem you have.    The real solution, however, is to add include guards to the headers.  Also, get out of the habit of `using namespace std` in header files.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the #include .cpp files, as Yksisarvinen mentioned, solved my problem.